# Converting desktop layout to single-column mobile layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I had an entire site created, but removed all the filler and left the 3-column divs. My goal is to have these 3 columns stack vertically as the image is resized.

The additional css is included as it was used with the rest of the site, so I included it all.

I tried looking up certain media queries and tried wrapping my head around flexbox. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
  * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*For layout purposes only*/
}

* {
  max-width: 980px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
```

```html
<header class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Instead of margin: 0 auto, put ' float: left'. It should stack when screen gets narrower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-direction: row`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction). That means that the children of the container ("flex items") will align horizontally, just like in your code.

To stack items vertically, switch to `flex-direction: column`.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
}
```

If you want flex items to stack vertically on resize, change the `flex-direction` in a media query:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 500px ) { 
     .row { flex-direction: column; }
   }
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nkc1wqhn/1/)

Comment: You got it , one last thing. I am having trouble centering the divs when the the screen size is reduced. They now stack , but for some reason the images seem to float right, but my links are centered. And when I try to justify the content to center it is non responsive.

Comment: The issue is `width: 33.33%` on `.col-4`, which persists after the media query triggers. By adjusting the rule in the media query to `width: 100%`, the problem appears to be solved. http://jsfiddle.net/nkc1wqhn/1/