# Flexbox layout. Unable to get boxes to same width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Been browsing the net for solutions to my problem getting all the flexboxes the same width, but with no luck. Therefore I try to ask you here.

As you might see, if the description is long, the box is also wider. Been playing around with `word-wrap: break-word;` without any luck.

See snippet below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pwar5v6/1/).

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons>a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.food-box {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  border-color: #d3e0e9;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9e5;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.food-box .food-box-image {
  position: absolute top: 0 left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/461198/pexels-photo-461198.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.food-box .food-box-content {
  position: absolute bottom: 0 left: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #e25822;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.food-box .food-box-badge {
  display: table;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-color: #d3e0e9;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9e5;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.food-box .food-box-badge span {
  color: #666;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="buttons">
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkNewTapas" OnClick="lnkNewTapas_OnClick">
    <div class="food-box">
      <div class="food-box-image" runat="server" id="foodBoxBGTapas">
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-badge">
        <span>Tapas</span>
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-content">
        Velsmakende og orientalske tapasretter!
      </div>
    </div>
  </asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkNavKoldtbord" OnClick="lnkNavKoldtbord_OnClick">
    <div class="food-box">
      <div class="food-box-image" runat="server" id="foodBoxBGKoldtbord">
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-badge">
        <span>Koldtbord</span>
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-content">
        Velg mellom våre to smakfulle koldtbordvarianter...
      </div>
    </div>
  </asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkPasmurt" OnClick="lnkPasmurt_OnClick">
    <div class="food-box">
      <div class="food-box-image" runat="server" id="foodBoxBGPasmurt">
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-badge">
        <span>Påsmurt</span>
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-content">
        Velg fritt i vårt store utvalg av baguetter, snitter, rundstykker.
      </div>
    </div>
  </asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkNewMed" OnClick="lnkNewMed_OnClick">
    <div class="food-box">
      <div class="food-box-image" runat="server" id="foodBoxBGMed">
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-badge">
        <span>Middelhavs buffét</span>
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-content">
        Orientalske matretter med spennende smaker!
      </div>
    </div>
  </asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkNewVarmmat" OnClick="lnkNewVarmmat_OnClick">
    <div class="food-box">
      <div class="food-box-image" runat="server" id="foodBoxBGVarmmat">
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-badge">
        <span>Varmmat</span>
      </div>
      <div class="food-box-content">
        Et stort utvalg av varmmatretter!
      </div>
    </div>
  </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: All you need is `flex: 1` on the flex items. https://jsfiddle.net/7pwar5v6/2/

Comment: @Michael_B : Tried that already, did not work... try for yourself :) 

I notice a lot of questions are marked duplicates many times... And 70% of the times, it's right.. In this case.. it was more of a general... "The original CSS messes up the flexbox-layout, and i could not figure out what was the reason in my case... 
I made tryouts with default flexbox "templates".. worked, i minified the CSS, stripped away styling and such... Success.. BUT!.. What i needed was exactly what i had made, and was not able to sort it out.. So therefore.. duplicate "tech issue" yes.. But not solution..

Comment: I did test your code. I also tested my solution. It worked. See the demo in my comment.

Comment: hmm.. yeah.. i see that you made it :) Maybe some of my code (or page-code) which wasn't correct.. 

Anyways.. do you know @Michael_B how i can make it responsive like max 4 when desktop and only 1 for each row on mobile ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33003652/3597276

Comment: Thanks for taking time @Michael_B :) Guess this should have been added as a new question, so let me know if you want me to create a new one... I guess some of my CSS are messing up things.. Can you take a look ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/00jy124e/3/

Comment: Finally!... Got it to work as i wanted ! https://jsfiddle.net/00jy124e/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/00jy124e/6/

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B for your help :) Finally understood a bit more about this flexstuff.. Been too "hooked" up with Bootstrap grid col's and row's..  But flexbox is a bit more "flexible"? hehe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these two setting and erasing the `width` from `.foodbox` should do the trick, since the `.foodbox` elements are *not* the flex items, but the flex-items'  children:

```
.buttons > * {
  width: 20%;
}
.buttons > * > *{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yuwhpgrn/2/

Comment: Thanks for 3 great answers guys!... Though all of them prolly solves the issue, i found @Johannes solution easiest without having to set a specified width to the food-box element itself... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add width to asp:LinkButton elements, something like:

```
[runat]{
   width: calc(100% / 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to solve by applying a fixed width on 'food-box' with overflow:hidden. I did away with 'break-word' and centered the content:

```
.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons > a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.food-box {
  flex: 1;
width: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  border-color: #d3e0e9;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9e5;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.food-box .food-box-image {
  position: absolute top: 0 left: 0;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/461198/pexels-photo-461198.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.food-box .food-box-content {
  position: absolute bottom: 0 left: 0;
/* word-wrap: break-word; */
text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #e25822;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 70%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.food-box .food-box-badge {
  display: table;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-color: #d3e0e9;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9e5;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.food-box .food-box-badge span {
  color: #666;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zornfett/8r4L2c3r/

Comment: Thanks @zornfett.. Should probably have noted it, but tried to stay away from specifying a constant width to the food-box :) Thanks though!